# Java problems with variable assignment

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have problems determining the order variables should be when assigning, specifically in cases where I am assigning an element of an array to a variable or when neither variable points to a meaningful value yet. For instance, knowing when to type `array[i] = x;` vs. `x = array[i]`, or `a=b` vs. `b=a`. I've used "points to" as a substitute for the `=`, but I am still making mistakes.

Comment: You need to write lots and lots of code, and then write some more.

Comment: Both are valid assignments. The "right" one depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Yeah, I know what I want the assignment to do, but I have trouble turning the code into plain language so I don't flip back and forth between the two. Thanks folks!

Comment: I would read `a = b` as "set a to the value of b"

Comment: The value always moves to the left. It's "sucked in" by the variable on the left side of the equals sign.

Comment: I'm realizing that this really does come down to a lack of experience, though everyone's comments and answers have helped--thank you! Please close as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment order is the same as in mathematical assignments. The left hand side is the one which gets modified. It is quite easy if you imagine a number of variables beeing assigned with longer expressions (on the right side):

```
a = 1 +2,
b = 2 * a;
```

As you can see, you have "room" on the right side.

Comment: @maurelius3 feel free to accept it as the answer, then.